# error in starting activity,

Tags: android

i have an activity that contains buttons that will guide me to next activity.

the problem is the first activity that contains those buttons give me this error.

can you explain what is that error?

Thank you.

```
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lspu.handbook/com.lspu.handbook.apr}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.lspu.handbook.apr.onCreate(apr.java:35)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  ... 11 more
```

here's my code:

```
public class apr extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.apr);

    Button ar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ar);
    ar.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg);
    reg.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button ta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ta);
    ta.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button vr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vr);
    vr.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button foreign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.foreign);
    foreign.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button non = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nonreg);
    non.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button cross = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cross);
    cross.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button scholar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scholar);
    scholar.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lspu_nxt_btn);
    nxt.setOnClickListener(this);




    StartAnimations();
}
     private void StartAnimations() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
            anim.reset();
            LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lspulayout);
            l.clearAnimation();
            l.startAnimation(anim);


            //back button
            Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lspu_bak_btn);
            backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent instructionsIntent = new Intent(apr.this,MainBookActivity.class);
                    startActivity(instructionsIntent);
                finish();
                }
             });

            }


     @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            System.gc();
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = null;

            switch( v.getId() ) {

            case R.id.ar:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_ar.class);
                break;

            case R.id.reg:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_reg.class);
                break;

            case R.id.ta:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_ta.class);
                break;

            case R.id.vr:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_vr.class);
                break;

            case R.id.foreign:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_foreign.class);
                break;

            case R.id.nonreg:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_nonreg.class);
                break;

            case R.id.cross:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_cross.class);
                break;

            case R.id.scholar:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hand_Book_scholar.class);
                break;

            case R.id.lspu_nxt_btn:
                intent = new Intent(this, apr2.class);
                break;


            default:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Do I missed the button you clicked?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            }

            // Open images
            if (intent != null) {
                intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

         @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                //Handle the back button
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    //Ask the user if they want to quit
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(R.string.quit)
                    .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            //Stop the activity
                            apr.this.finish();    
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                    .show();

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                }

            }
}
```

here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menubg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lspulayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tirlw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/titleapr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Admission Requirements"
    android:textSize="17dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Registration"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Transfer Admision"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Validation Requirements"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/foreign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Foreign Student Admission"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nonreg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Non-Regular Admission"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cross"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Cross Registration"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scholar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnallctr"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:text="Scholarship"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/lspu_bak_btn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backbtncntrl_hd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lspu_nxt_btn"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lspu_bak_btn"
    android:background="@drawable/nxtbtncntrl_hd" />

</RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

to those who helps, thanks!

Comment: It is NullException. Check your code at line 35. 08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-06 05:16:53.278: E/AndroidRuntime(771): at com.lspu.handbook.apr.onCreate(apr.java:35)

Comment: post your code.please

Comment: exception is at line 35 ,check your 35 line code

Comment: post u r xml file also it will help to trace the error it might possible the id u r using here is not in the XML file

Comment: @Jerome it happens just post u r xml also peoples wants here to show they are very smart.post u r xml lets see what is the problem

Comment: clean your project , you will get any xml related error if exists

Comment: @Jerome did you clean your project?

Comment: yes, but the same error again, in my other activity it works and doesn't have an error, just this one.

Comment: are you sure the name of the xml is correct? I mean, have you named this xml file as apr.xml?

Comment: I run your code in eclipse, it's ok. check your xml file name of activity

Comment: the name in my activity is the same as the name of the xml file.

Comment: what is line 35 exactly? I can't tell without line numbers which line is causing the issue.  Have you tried using the debugger to step through and look at the value of values as they're set?

Answer (score 0):

`at com.lspu.handbook.apr.onCreate(apr.java:35)` points to the fact that the button is not initialized or in other words it is null. In your code, you are instantiating the `Button` objects in `onCreate()` method, thus all those buttons have the scope local to `onCreate()` once onCreate() returns, those buttons go out of scope, so when you click any button, you get `NullPointerException`. The easy solution is to create all button objects outside the method and then instanti0ate them inside `onCreate()`.

```
 Button ar,reg,ta,vr,foreign,non,cross,scholar,nxt;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

this.setContentView(R.layout.apr);

 ar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ar);
ar.setOnClickListener(this);

 reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg);
reg.setOnClickListener(this);

 ta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ta);
ta.setOnClickListener(this);

 vr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vr);
vr.setOnClickListener(this);

 foreign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.foreign);
foreign.setOnClickListener(this);

 non = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nonreg);
non.setOnClickListener(this);

 cross = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cross);
cross.setOnClickListener(this);

 scholar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scholar);
scholar.setOnClickListener(this);

 nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lspu_nxt_btn);
nxt.setOnClickListener(this);




StartAnimations();
```

}